# Prevent Capistrano deploy for asking Multi-User server password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, permissions, capistrano

I have two Ubuntu users they are **deploy** and **developers**. The Rails application with Capistrano is installed in **deploy** user.

So basically the **deploy** user will change the password. I granted permission to **developers** user to access and deploy the rails application.

But the problem is when I login as **developers** user to access and deploy the application under **deploy** user, it is asking for the server password.

```
developers@stg_tx_app1:/home/deploy$ cap staging deploy
deploy@10.0.18.238's password:
```

The config in **deploy.rb** is

```
server XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db}
```

the user is deploy because it is where the application is deployed.

How can I prevent Capistrano to ask for the server's password?

Answer (score 0):

When you explicitly provide `user: 'deploy'` and set method of authentication as password, then it will definitely ask for it's password. No other go!

If you have qualms about this technique, I will suggest you use `ssh-keys` for deploying using Capistrano.

---

Let me know if what I said makes sense. I can write more about this `ssh-keys` technique, you can let me know by writing a comment below.